# batch file if statement for removing/adding from registry

Tags: windows, if-statement, batch-file, registry

I am wondering if someone could tell me how to create a batch file that removes a key/value from the registry if it's there, and adds it if it's not?

Answer (score 0):

I've made a function:

```
@Echo OFF

:: By Elektro H@cker

REM CALL :REGIF "KEY\SUBKEY" 
REM or
REM CALL :REGIF "KEY\SUBKEY" /V "VALUE"

REM Examples:
Call :REGIF "HKLM\Key that fails"
Call :REGIF "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU"
Call :REGIF "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU" /V "MRUListEx"
Pause&Exit

:REGIF
REG QUERY %* 1>NUL 2>&1 && (
    REG DELETE %* /F 1>NUL
    Echo [+] Key deleted: %* | MORE
) || (
    REM added value is default SZ type.
    REG ADD %* /F >NUL
        Echo [+] Key added: %* | MORE
)
GOTO:EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
set name=HKLM\SOFTWARE\key /v value
reg query %name%
if %errorlevel%==0 (
reg delete %name% /f
) else (
if %errorlevel%==1 reg add %name% /d "data" /f
)
```